# Unable to run Selenium / WebDriver in eclipse for Chrome browser in java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

my chrome version is Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit) and chrome driver version is ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23  and same code working on IntelliJ IDEA and giving following error while runing in eclipse.

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
(Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19041 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.41 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: ', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
at practice.PracticeClass.main(PracticeClass.java:10)

Comment: already downloaded  and replaced with 89.0.4389.23/ and give same error

Comment: the chromedriver the Eclipse project is pointing to is clearly different than the one you are using in IntelliJ.  You need to track it down and figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Download  chromedriver 89 from link https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and replace on your local device.

Comment: already downloaded  and replaced with 89.0.4389.23/ and give same error

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to version compatibility. Your chrome driver version is not matching with your chrome browser version. You may download compatible chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads